# Uncheck one checkbox, unchecks all other checkboxes Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox, when i click one checkbox (ckbox3), 3 options with checkboxes are shown(check1, check2, check3). When i uncheck ckbox3, i want check1, check2 and check3 to be unchecked. I am not sure how to do this

Can someone help me out with Javascript code.. (I need solution with Javascript)

**HTML**:

```
    <div id="divv1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ckbox3" >Checkbox1 &nbsp;  
    </div>
    <br>           


    <div id="divv2">
         <input type="checkbox" name="check1" onclick="calculate()" id="check1">check 1
         <input type="checkbox" name="check2" onclick="calculate()" id="check2">check 2
         <input type="checkbox" name="check3" onclick="calculate()" id="check3">check 3
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
document.getElementById('ckbox3').onclick = function() {
     if(ckbox3.checked){          
           toggleSub(this, 'divv2');
     } else {  
           toggleSub(this, 'divv2');
     }
};

function toggleSub(box,id)
{
    var el = document.getElementById(id);

    if ( box.checked ) {
            el.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

**CSS**:

```
#divv2
{
 display: none;
 margin-left: 75px;
 font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;

}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vikrams/hLmneafj/1/

Comment: Not clear what you want. You want the checkboxes to be unchecked, then why are you hiding the checkboxes when `ckbox3` is unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a onchange fuction on ckbox3 :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ckbox3" onchange = "change()" >
```

and in fuction:

```
function change()
{
if(document.getElementById("ckbox3").checked == false){
document.getElementById("check1").checked = false;
document.getElementById("check2").checked = false;
document.getElementById("check3").checked = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `generic` code you can give any number of check boxes inside `div`.

```js
 document.getElementById('ckbox3').onclick = function() {
                if(ckbox3.checked)
                {
                    
                    toggleSub(this,true);
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    toggleSub(this, false);
                }
                };
                
                function toggleSub(box,status)
                {
                    var div = document.getElementById("divv2");
                    var el = div.getElementsByTagName("input");
                   var len = el.length;
                    while(len--)
                    {
                    
                       div.getElementsByTagName("input")[len].checked = status;
                    }
                    
                }
```

```html
<div id="divv1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="ckbox3" >Checkbox1 &nbsp;
            
        </div>
        <br>           
                   
              
        <div id="divv2">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" onclick="calculate()" id="check1">check 1
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check2" onclick="calculate()" id="check2">check 2
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check3" onclick="calculate()" id="check3">check 3
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='check']");
for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
   arr[i].checked=false;
}
```

[Here is your updated **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p8dLLv6m/)

Add the above code in the `else` section of your code to uncheck the rest when `ckbox3` is unchecked, as shown in the JSFiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code below

```
$("#ckbox3").change(function () {
$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have look on following code:

```html
<script>

function handleClick(element){
 if (element.checked == true){
  document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;
  document.getElementById("check2").checked = true;
  document.getElementById("check3").checked = true;
 }else{
  document.getElementById("check1").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("check2").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("check3").checked = false;
 }
}
</script>
<div id="divv1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="masterCheckbox" onclick='handleClick(this);'> Checkbox1 &nbsp;
    </div>
    <br>           


    <div id="divv2">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check1" onclick="calculate()" id="check1">check 1
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" onclick="calculate()" id="check2">check 2
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check3" onclick="calculate()" id="check3">check 3
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your else part :

```
else 
{
    el.style.display = 'none';      
    var checks = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id + ' input[type="checkbox"]');
    for(var i =0; i< checks.length;i++){
        var check = checks[i];
        if(!check.disabled){
            check.checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/hLmneafj/4/